# How can I convert list items to input elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form, and I need to convert the  list items to inputs so I can submit them via POST. I've tried to append to each list items a hidden input. Here's my code:

```js
function add() {
   

 let ul = document.getElementById('basket-list');
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let item = document.getElementById('code-input');
    
    // Here I try to append an hidden input, but it's not working
    let input = document.createElement('input')
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    input.setAttribute("name", "name");
    input.setAttribute("value", "value");
    
    //li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));
    //item.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    console.log(ul);
    let lis = document.getElementById('basket-list').childNodes;
    let list = [];
    for( let i = 1; i < lis.length; i++ ){
        let li = lis[i];
        list.push(li.textContent);
    }
    console.log(list);
    
}
```

```html
<form action="">
         <ul id="basket-list"> 
         </ul>
         <div class="basket-inputs">
            <input type="text" class="code-input" id="code-input" name="code-input" placeholder="Código">
            <button type="button" onclick="add()" ><i class="fas fa-check">Add</i></button>
         </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: `input.setAttribute("value", item.value);
li.append(input);
li.textContent=item.value;`

Comment: All that's wrong is that you forgot to append the new input to your `li`. You also should give the input an appropriate name and value, but I guess that is just for testing at the moment :)

Comment: Thanks! yes, i'm testing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing purposes, I used `text` elements instead of hidden.

The two big things is, appending the `input` and appending the text node of item.value so you can see the text that was added.

```
li.appendChild(input);
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.value));
```

```js
function add() {
        let ul = document.getElementById('basket-list');
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        let item = document.getElementById('code-input');
        
        // Here I try to append an hidden input, but it's not working
        let input = document.createElement('input')
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        input.setAttribute("name", "name");
        input.setAttribute("value", item.value);
        
        li.appendChild(input);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.value));
        
        ul.appendChild(li);
        
        let lis = document.getElementById('basket-list').childNodes;
        let list = [];
        for( let i = 1; i < lis.length; i++ ){
            let li = lis[i];
            list.push(li.textContent);
        }
        console.log(list);
        
    }
```

```html
<form action="">
         <ul id="basket-list">
         </ul>
         <div class="basket-inputs">
            <input type="text" class="code-input" id="code-input" name="code-input" placeholder="Código">
            <button type="button" onclick="add()" ><i class="fas fa-check">Add</i></button>
         </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Oh! right, also value attribute has to be the item.value, i see. Thanks!